# Unsigned 64-bit bitwise AND/OR in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I've looked through Stack Overflow and haven't quite found an answer for this.  I have bitmask values that go from `0x0000000000000001` to `0x0200000000000000,` each representing a field in my object that can be modified.  Modified fields have their corresponding mask value bitwise-OR'd together to have a single 64-bit value that can be interpreted later.  But I'm having difficulties because the Javascript bitwise operators convert the operands to 32-bit signed values.  I tried to write unsigned 64-bit unsigned methods to mimic bitwise-OR and bitwise-AND, but ran into difficulties.  My first stab was:

```
    _bitwiseOr64: function(a, b) {
         var aHi = (a >> 32);
         var aLo = (a & 0xffffffff);
         var bHi = (b >> 32);
         var bLo = (b & 0xffffffff);
         return (((aHi | bHi) << 32) + (aLo | bLo));
    }
```

If `a = 0` and `b = 0x80000000`, I'd want the result of _bitwiseOr64 to be `0x80000000` (unsigned because I'm dealing with bitmasks here).  I'm not getting that result.  Can anyone offer help?

Comment: The problem is that js only supports 52 bit integers. That's because js numbers are doubles and doubles have 11 bit exponent and 52 bit mantissa (the remaining 1 bit is the sign bit). If you need to represent a 64 bit number the best you can do is use an array of two 32 bit numbers.

Comment: Take a look at typed arrays such as [`Uint32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this library: http://google.github.io/closure-library/api/class_goog_math_Long.html

They have multiple bitwise functionality like add(other) and or(other) that support 64-bit as well.

For Node.JS, you can use [Long.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/long)

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it as answer.